# Full width/height div css specifics

Tags: html, css

Considering I aim modern desktop and mobile browsers, is there any practical difference in which one of the following css rules to use? Are there any hidden caveats?

```
.modal-1{
   position:fixed;
   top:0; 
   right:0; 
   bottom:0; 
   left:0;
}

.modal-2{
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

.modal-3{
   position:fixed;
   min-width:100%;
   min-height:100%;
}
```

And a sub-question: what if everything is the same, except `position:absolute;`, when I want to make a modal div inside another (relative or absolute positioned) div and not `body`, is there any difference in css rules then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your classes used with a `div`:

Using `modal-1` seems not to add any margins at all and is fully responsive due to its nature.

`modal-2` and `modal-3` inherit parent margins in Firefox, not in Chrome though, `body { margin: 0 0 0 0; }` fixes it (in my test case `body` was the parent element.)

Using `top, right, bottom, left` appears to be the most fail-safe choice, in my opinion it's best used with `@media (min-width:***px)` query to help arrange the layers within the fixed container.

As for your sub-question, any child element (sub-modal) should best use `position: relative` and set itself within using `top, left, width and height`. You could also manipulate `overflow` in case of troubles.

I hope that answers your question(s).

Answer (score -1):

your main container dive should have position:relative and if you want full screen width:100% and height:100% with display:block ...

for position children div inside parent they should have absolute position